bcrypt.compare always returns false when comparing passwords
For some reason bcrypt.compare stopped working and doMatch always returns false. I'm able to create new users with hashed password but then cannot log in for the aforementioned reason. My login controller is:
  const postLoginController = async (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  try {
    User.findOne({ email: email }).then((user) => {
      console.log('password, user.password', password, user.password);
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then((doMatch) => {
        console.log('doMatch', doMatch);
        //Comparing the password the user entered with the password stored in the db
        if (doMatch) {
          console.log('passwords match');
          req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
          req.session.user = user;
          req.session.save();
          res.status(200).json({ isLoggedIn: true, message: 'Logged in!' });
        } else {
          res
            .status(401)
            .json({ isLoggedIn: false, message: 'Invalid credentials. Please try again.' });
        }
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: 'Failed to login.' });
  }
};

The console.log returns both the string and the hashed passwords:
password, user.password 123456 $2a$12$9YqCOmycoiLJ8uf7HfL4HebR2hHrJ7b2e6YspG7cP8.6UeAbapHEm

However, as I mentioned, comparing them results in doMatch always being false. Any idea why this is happening? It was working previously. I reinstalled bcryptjs, which is at version 2.4.3 currently, but it didn't help.
I'm adding the hashing code (the controller that creates the hashed password) as well:
const postSignupController = async (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  try {
    User.findOne({ email: email }).then((userDoc) => {
      if (userDoc) {
        res.status(409).json({ isLoggedIn: false, message: 'The user already exists.' });
        return;
      } else {
        res.status(200).json({ isLoggedIn: true, message: 'Signed up' });
        return bcrypt.hash(password, 12).then((hashedPassword) => {
          const user = new User({
            email: email,
            password: hashedPassword,
            cart: { items: [] },
          });
          return user.save();
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: 'Failed to sign up.' });
  }
};


do you have the hashing code as well. i hope there is no double hashing happening somewhere. or maybe an int issue. parse 123456 to string and compare

@cmgchess I think your intuition is correct, more than likely some sort of double hashing is happening here. bcrypt will not allow you to use number to compare with hash, it requires string... So the number highlighting we are getting here is from SO.

I've added the hashing code - the postSignupController, as requested.

hi, make sure you aren't double hashing it in your User model or somewhere else. also if you are locally using mongo make sure, your hashpasswords are not corrupted.

@ishaan, I only use the hashing once in the postSignupController listed above, when a new user is created. I have no idea how to check if hashpasswords are not corrupted.

I discovered the problem and fixed it. I was sending the email as a password on user creation with axios:
await axios
      .post(`/auth/signup`, {
        email: state.userEmail,
        password: state.userEmail, //should be state.userPassword
      })

It was a typo on the frontend and I spent hours trying to fix it on the backend. So, I was hashing the mail instead of the password and then trying to login with the password. Logging with the email as password worked.
As a result of this, in the postSignupController, I was receiving the email here:
const password = req.body.password;

